# Regular Expression for at least one alphanumeric or digit

Tags: regex

I need to identify a string contain at least one character or digit and it may contain special character too

`@#$@$#@$`   --- false

`@#$@$#@$1`  --- true

`@#$@$#@$w`  --- true

`@#$@$#@$R`  --- true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below pattern should work for you

```
[\d\w]  or [a-zA-Z0-9]
```